# Stream MP4 instead of downloading with Express

Tags: node.js, express, http, video-streaming

I have a URI that can download an mp4 file, I'm trying to create a proxy that will stream that file instead of downloading it, but everything I've tried still downloads the file instead of streaming it. Content-Type is set to video/mp4, and that's the only answer that I've been able to find

```
res.contentType('video/mp4');
req.pipe(request.get(url.fullUrl)).pipe(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a readable stream then pipe it to the response, something like this:

```
const path = 'video.mp4';

const head = {
    'Content-Length': 123456, // Get the video file size,
    'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
}

res.writeHead(200, head);
fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res);
```

Comment: I managed to get it to load the video player with req.pipe(request.get(url.fullUrl).pipe(res)), but no video loads and no data is sent, can't use fs.createReadStream because the file isn't on the system